# file upload not working in laravel with mamp server

Tags: file, file-upload, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following store method for upload a file.

```
public function store()
    {
        //

        $rules = [];
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        // if the validator fails, redirect back to the form
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::back()
                ->withErrors($validator) // send back all errors to the login form
                ->withInput();
        } else {

            $klas = new Klas;
            $klas ->title =  Input::get('title');
            if (Input::get('active') === 'yes') {
                $klas ->active = 1;
            } else {
                $klas ->active = 0;
            }


            $extension = 'png';
            $directory = public_path() . '/uploads/klassen';
            $filename = Input::get('title').".{$extension}";

            $upload_success = Input::file('image',$directory,$filename);

            //Upload the file
            if($upload_success){
                $klas->image = $filename;
                $klas -> save();
                $klassen = DB::table('klas')->get();

                return View::make('klas.index',compact('klassen'));
            }



        }
    }
```

My `'klas'` is succefully saved into the database also with the correct file name. But the file is not uploaded?  I've set the `public , uploads and klassen folder` to read write for everyone already.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the file to the target directory:

```
$file = Input::file('image');
$file->move($directory, $filename);
```

I'm not sure if taking the 2nd and 3rd argument like you're doing now works.